# ItemsControl ignores DataTemplates in Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I want to bind a collection of multiple types to an ItemsControl being displayed in a canvas. My code so far is the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects}">
     <ItemsControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="self:CalibrationRectangle">
             <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="self:PolygonVM">
             <Polygon Fill="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Points="{Binding Points}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.Resources>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas Background="Red" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <!--<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="self:CalibrationRectangle">
             <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>-->
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style>
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
         </Style>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

In this state of the code the DataTemplates in the Resources are completely ignored and instead objects are represented as strings.
If instead I use the commented out lines and define the DataTemplate in ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate it works. However, as I need multiple DataTemplates (one per type) this is no solution.

What is the problem here? Why are the DataTemplates in the resources not working?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: What are `self:CalibrationRectangle` and `selfPolygonVM`? Because it seems to me you are applying your `DataTemplate` to a Type that is not used in your `ItemsControl`

Comment: Those are just some own types having the bound fields as properties. They both have the same parent type called DrawableVM. The bound collection Objects is then just an ObservableCollection<DrawableVM>. So my ItemsControl should use these types or am I getting something worng?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment you target XML element name. If you want to target type you need to use `{x:Type ...}` and replace

```
<DataTemplate DataType="self:CalibrationRectangle">
```

with

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:CalibrationRectangle}">
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> To refer to the type name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension. If the template is intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name.

Comment: Thank you :) It's working now. But can you explain what the difference between those two is?

Comment: I've just edited my answer to add more info but basically without that you target XML element name